# dlang map! int to string array

Tags: d, map-function

getClass and getTitle return both an `string` type
Obviously another array is being returned but I am not sure if the types are being correctly inferred, is this the case?

How is this an error in D?
I had tried writeln(Array int) before but somehow it's not working with map! strings

```
writeln(listChildren().map!(x=>getClass(x)));
```

> [x"46 6F 72 65 67 72 6F 75 6E 64 53 74 61 67 69 6E 67 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF"c, x"46 6F 72 65 67 72 6F 75 6E 64 53 74 61 67 69 6E 67 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF"c, x"74 6F 6F 6C 74 69 70 73 5F 63 6C 61 73 73 33 32 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF"c, ...]

```
writeln(listChildren().map!(x=>getTitle(x)));
```

> ["\0", "\0", "\0", "\0", "\0", "\0", "\0", "\0", "\0", "\0", "\0", "\0", "\0", "\0", "\0", "geany.exe\0", "\0", "\0", x"4D 65 64 69 64 6F 72 20 64 65 20 6C 61 20 62 61 74 65 72 ED 61 00"c, "\0", "Network Flyout\0", "\0", "\0", "geany.exe\0", "geany.exe\0", "geany.exe\0", "geany.exe\0", "geany.exe\0", "geany.exe\0", ...]

Note: when I use

```
listChildren().map!getClass.each!writeln;
```

I get the expected results but I need to work with the previous form to compose the new values

Comment: try adding `.to!(string[]).join("\n")` if the each!writeln is the expected result

Comment: That works! but what is going on, can't writeln print an string array correctly? btw it's `.map!(to!string).join("\n")`

Comment: it does `.to!string` on the argument and an array gets converted to a string a bit like this: `"[" ~ arr.each!(a => a.to!string).join(", ") ~ "]"`. There is not really any way else. Do you want each entry in a new line? Do you want them space separated, not separated at all? + It could look like a bug if you have empty strings in there and "nothing" is being outputted

Comment: Oh ok, the values were already returned as string by getClass and getTitle but I was expecting that writeln printed correctly the array as it does with int arrays without the need to add join

Comment: It prints int arrays like this too though (`[0, 1, 2, 3, ...]`)

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code:

```
auto s = [1, 2, 3].map!(a => a.to!string);
pragma(msg, typeof(s));
```

You can see that the return type of `map` is `MapResult` which can be used to be iterated on.

`map` is a lazy function that only evaluates the value when its requested, so you need to consume all the elements of the result to get what you need.

Add `.array()` after `.map` in order to consume all elements and convert the result to an array, then `writeln` them, you will get the same output of an integer array.

```
writeln(listChildren().map!(x => getClass(x)).array());
```

Comment: Do I need to import something in order to use `.array()`? I get `Error: no property 'array' for type 'MapResult!(__lambda2, void*[])'`

Comment: ok I imported `std.array:array` but I am getting the same unformatted output on a string[]

Comment: what is the return type of `getClass` ? if its `void*` and you intend to return a string, just return a string

Comment: it returns a d string